# How to make login token for certain time , such as 1h or 1d in this login.ts file?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

1) How to make token login generator for certain time in this login.ts file ?

2) Also I need to setItem to localStorage if no internet connection for user on terrain.

Thanks a lot for help.

```
 login() {
        let user = {
          "username": this.username,
          "password": this.password
        }

        this.peopleProvider.callWebApi(user)
          .subscribe(
          result => {

            console.log('Result from server:', result);

            if (result.result == "true") {
              this.presentLoading();

              localStorage.setItem("username", result.username);
              localStorage.setItem("password", result.password);
              localStorage.setItem("firstname", result.firstname);
              localStorage.setItem("lastname", result.lastname);
              localStorage.setItem("userId", result.userId);


               this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);

              this.loader.dismiss();

            }

            else {

              this.presentAlert();
              //this.loader.dismiss();
              this.invalidLogin = true;

            }
          },
          error => {

          }
          );
   }
```

Comment: where you are storing token ?

Comment: Hm....mssql or localstorage.